# How to update IntelliJ IDEA testing-plugin to TestNG version 6.8?

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

Currently, I am using [TestNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestNG) 6.8 with [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), but when I run the test through the [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) plugin, it uses an old version of TestNG.

How can I make IntelliJ IDEA (version 11.1.4) work with TestNG 6.8?

Answer (score 8):

1. Download the [complete TestNG 6.8 zip](http://testng.org/testng-6.8.zip).
2. Delete `IDEA\plugins\testng\lib\testng-jdk15.jar`.
3. Copy `testng-6.8.jar` from the downloaded zip into `IDEA\plugins\testng\lib`.

For IDEA 12+: replace `testng.jar` instead of `testng-jdk15.jar`.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked even that i did the same before(did not work) :)

Comment: @CrazyCoder. In the lib folder there are 2 jars: testng.jar, testng-jdk15.jar. Which one should We replace with new testng version? Seems testng-jdk15.jar is different from testng.jar. BUT when i replace testng.jar to new one all run test menu(mouse right click) are gone. Plugin stopped working, Any ideas?

Comment: @elbek, replace `testng-jdk15.jar`, `testng.jar` is the integration plug-in itself and must remain there (the name is changed to 'testng-plugin.jar' in IDEA 12 to avoid this kind of confusion and if you are using IDEA 12 or later, `testng.jar` needs to be replaced instead).

Comment: I upgraded but it stopped working. testng-jdk15 size is 1.2Mb. lates version of testng is 600-700KB, how come it may work. I opened testng-jdk15 and it contains junit and other tools. After upgrade when i run test against a method it is telling no test suite. Thanks for answer

Comment: @elbek, you are using the wrong jar, please use the one from the link in my answer. The one from Maven is not complete!

Comment: @CrazyCoder Update worked, I did not know that it was incomplete. However i am having this issue: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/440721 still

Comment: It's already spelled out in the answer, but it's worth reiterating here that when you copy the new `testng-6.8.jar` into the plugins directory, you do not need to rename it to match the file you deleted (I did that first, and it obviously did not work).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way: In "Project Structure" -> "Modules" -> "Dependencies", click the left bottom "+" to add a new dependency from either pre-downloaded jar file, or library from Maven repository. Remember to remove the old TestNG version, or move the new version to above that.