# Intellij with TestNG report generation

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

I am not able to generate report using TestNG+Intellij 12, also provided out path in Run configuration.
I have even updated to TestNG 6.8 by this way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452828/1434611

Can anyone provide some input if you are able to generate reports.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

At the top **select the dropdown** and click on **edit configuration**

[image]

[image: Check on Use default reporters option]
Check on **Use default reporters** which is under listner tab option which will create test-output folder in your root folder with all reports.

Comment: Thank you so much, Worked for me as well

Comment: Works Like a charm! Thankyou!

Answer (score 10):

One thing that you can consider to do is, that you check the checkbox under Listeners. This checkbox enables the automated reports. You have to change the default settings of TestNG run options to enable it for any additional runs after the first one. This solved my reporting problems.

Answer (score 6):

You can add Listener like "EmailableReporter" or "FailedReporter" in the "Run Configurations",
it will generate test-output directory in your workspace.

I test it at Intellj IDEA 12.0.4

Answer (score 6):

From Edit Configurations

1. On the "Listeners tab", Use default listeners should be checked.
2. And Output directory should be set correctly.