# The 'test-output' folder is not created when running TestNG Selenium test outside of Eclipse

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

1. We created some java code (`selenium webdriver` script) with Eclipse.
2. Inside my project I used `selenium jar` files and `TestNG jar`
3. While running these scripts we go test output folder within Eclipse.
4. Then we created an executable `jar` from the script what we generated and while running this generated jar we are not getting the TestNG **test-output** folder.

Please suggest how could we create **test-output** folder while running our executable `jar`.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457499/intellij-with-testng-report-generation/48165623

Answer (score 2):

After you run the scripts just refresh the project.
[Right-click the project-> Properties-> Click Refresh]
You can now see the test-output folder in your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added all the JARs like

1. ReportNG JAR
2. Guice JAR
3. Velocity dep JAR.

And press F5 after running your program. If still issue persists, restart the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the checkbox and name the output folder as test-output

[image: 1]